# VBA - Remove duplicates from bottom

Tags: excel, vba, loops, duplicates

I am running a loop to add notes to the end of a running list. I am having a problem removing duplicates based on an identifier in column 1. The following code works if the duplicates are exactly the same in both columns.

```
Sub Note_update()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim notes_ws As Worksheet
Dim row
Dim lastrow
Dim notes_nextrow

'find the worksheet called notes
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Notes" Then
        Set notes_ws = ws
    End If
Next ws

'get the nextrow to print to
notes_nextrow = notes_ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

'loop through other worksheets
For Each ws In Worksheets
    'ignore the notes worksheet
    If ws.Name <> "Notes" And ws.Index > Sheets("Master").Index Then
        'find lastrow
        lastrow = ws.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        For row = 2 To lastrow
            'if the cell is not empty
            If ws.Range("L" & row) <> "" Then
                notes_ws.Range("B" & notes_nextrow).Value = ws.Range("L" & row).Value
                notes_ws.Range("A" & notes_nextrow).Value = ws.Range("F" & row).Value
                notes_nextrow = notes_nextrow + 1
            End If
        Next row
    End If
Next ws

notes_ws.Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

If I change the last line of the following code, it will remove duplicates based solely on the identifier in the first column.

```
notes_ws.Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlYes
```

The problem is that it removes the duplicate from the bottom of the list but the bottom is the most recent note that I'd like to keep.

QUESTION: How do I remove the duplicates and leave the bottom-most note based solely on column 1?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Since the behavior of the 'RemoveDuplicates' is functioning properly, one solution would be to find the last row, alter the value in either Col A or B, delete dups then put the value back. But it sounds like if your last two rows are duplicates, you still need to delete the first of that pair? If so, you still could do it by checking after all else is done and delete one row.

Comment: First, if you have a date field, you can sort it first from newest to oldest then remove duplicates. Otherwise, you can't do this using the built in *.RemoveDuplicates method*. It can be done using VBA, but it will not be simple if you want to emulate how the built-in remove duplicates works. If it is just one or 2 columns and solely based on one column (for checking of duplicates) that might be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an additional piece of code that inserts a column to the left and adds the row number, which tracks the order of the comments. Then I sorted descending so that the oldest comments go to the bottom of the list. Then I removed duplicates and re-sort the list and remove the number column.

Here is the updated code that follows the loop:

```
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Insert
For i = 1 To notes_nextrow
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Formula = "=row()"
Next i
Columns("A:A").Copy
Columns("A:A").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Range("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
notes_ws.Range("A:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
Range("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Columns("A:A").Delete
Range("a1").Select
```